# Update wont work on ".sortable" list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use a Jquery "sortable" list on my wordpress website but for some reason while it is sortable it does not seem to run the update function!

Here is the code I am using:

**Header Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-list").sortable({
    handle : '.handle',
    update : function () {
       var homepageorder = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
      $("#testinfo").load("process-sortable.php?"+homepageorder);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**Body Code:**

```
<pre>
<div id="testinfo">Waiting for update</div>
</pre>
<ul id="test-list">

<?php
$dbhost                         = "**********";
$dbuser                         = "**********";
$dbpass                         = "**********";
$dbname                         = "**********";

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");

mysql_select_db("arcadetheme1", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM homepageorder ORDER BY position") or die(mysql_error());;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<li id="listItem_'.$row['id'].'"><img src="http://localhost/new-arcade-theme-one/wp-content/themes/fungames/images/arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item '.$row['id'].'</strong></li>';
}

mysql_close($con);


?> 
</ul>
```

**process-sortable:**

```
$dbhost                         = "**********";
$dbuser                         = "**********";
$dbpass                         = "**********";
$dbname                         = "**********";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) :
$query = "UPDATE `homepageorder` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$sql[] = "UPDATE `homepageorder` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
endforeach;

print_r ($sql);
```

I have tried this code on its own and it seems to work perfectly but as soon as I add it to WordPress it just wont update!

If anyone can help me with this I would be massively grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery.noConflict()`, as there might be conflicting versions of jQuery in the final code.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j("#test-list").sortable({
    handle : '.handle',
    update : function () {
      var homepageorder = $j('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
      $j("#testinfo").load("process-sortable.php?"+homepageorder);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

See http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Comment: Hi,I have tried adding the "noConfilt()" but it is still not working. I have discovered that it is an error between the update function and the php file because as I know everything upto the "$j("#testinfo").load("process-sortable.php?"+homepageorder);" works fine.... I am confused :s